# What is the best approach to consume WCF external service data from SharePoint 2010 Web part?

Tags: ajax, rest, wcf, sharepoint

What is the best approach to consume WCF external service data from SharePoint 2010 Web part?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in a Visual Studio solution, you just have to :

1. Right click on the "References" of the projet WebPart.
2. Click on Add Service Reference
3. Put the url of your Web Service then click on OK.
4. Visual Studio'll generate a service client proxy. Use it to call your Web Service

More information here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb628652(v=vs.100).aspx